# List previous prime numbers of n

Tags: python, prime-factoring

I am trying to create a program in python that takes a number and determines whether or not that number is prime, and if it is prime I need it to list all of the prime numbers before it. What is wrong with my code?

```
import math
def factor(n):
    num=[]
    for x in range(2,(n+1)):
        i=2
        while i<=n-1:
            if n % i == 0:
                break
            i = i + 1
        if i > abs(n-1):
            num.append(n)
            print(n,"is prime",num)
        else:
            print(i,"times",n//i,"equals",n)
    return
```

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong with it?

Answer (score 0):

Your method only returns whether the 'n' is prime or not.
For this purpose, you don't need a nested loop. Just like this

```
def factor(n):
    num=[]
    for x in range(2,(n+1)):
        if n % x == 0:
            break
    if x > abs(n-1):
        num.append(n)
        print(n,"is prime",num)
    else:
        print(x,"times",n//x,"equals",n)
    return
```

And then, if you want all the other primes less than n, you can use prime number sieve algorithm.

--------- Update --------------

A modification of your code which can find the other primes (but prime sieve algorithm still has better performance than this)

```
def factor(n):
    num=[]
    for x in range(2,(n+1)):
        i=2
        while i<=x-1:
            if x % i == 0:
                break
            i = i + 1
        if i > abs(x-1):
            num.append(x)
    if n in num:
        print num
    else:
        print str(n) + ' is not num'
    return
```